# Run html file in command powershell

Tags: html, reactjs, powershell

Is it possible to run the react js/ts file in the powershell command without having to `npm run start`, so I want only one click and the file appears in Chrome or in Firefox

I'm just asking everyone, if you can't help, it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible, because the React code is a just a JS code. It uses Babel (if not mistaken) to generate JS code that is being inserted in one HTML document into div with "root" id. It might look like a valid HTML, but it is not.